# Faster runtime using random.choice(list) or random.randint(0,len(list)-1) in python?

Tags: python, algorithm, random

This might sound subjective, but it is not. I have an algorithm that runs until it visits all elements in a list, selecting the index randomly on each cycle. The list initially contains N # of booleans equal to `False`. Once an element is visited, its value is changed to `True`. If all elements read `True`, then the algorithm finishes. Assume that you cannot change the underlying algorithm, only the implementation.

Currently it runs too slowly for me to scale it so I'm looking for ways to reduce the runtime. One potential bottleneck I think is the random choice of element. Currently I'm using:

```
choice = random.choice(list)
```

Instead of

```
choice = list[random.randint(0,len(list)-1)]
```

I don't know the specifics of the underlying implementation of either `random.choice()` or `random.randint()`, does anyone know which is more efficient?

Comment: I don't know, why don't you [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html)?

Comment: You're right, it's not subjective, it is empirically measurable. So go and do so, after all only you have access to the machine this code runs on. Or even better yet, step up your game and get better at guessing which parts are potential bottlenecks. This is certainly not one. In fact, on my machine, your second code takes more than twice as much long according to `timeit`.

Comment: There's no need to be rude @delnan. Your comment serves it purpose just as well without the tone you use in sentence 2. I'm actually relatively new to using python and was unaware of `timeit`. Now I know :).

Comment: I'm sorry, that was indeed unhelpful. Blind guessing as an optimization strategy bugs me a lot. It's a waste of everyone's time, including the one doing the guesswork. Please, if you don't have the background to make an educated guess on this topic, **measure** instead of guessing (and of course, still test your guesses when you can make good guesses).

Comment: Why can't you change your algorithm? You're using an [O(n log n)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem) algorithm but there is an obvious O(n) algorithm.

Comment: Actually I should have said your algorithm has *average* time proportional to n log n. Its maximum running time is unbounded. There is an easy algorithm that is always Θ(n).

Comment: @robmayoff what is your O(n) solution? This is part of a larger program where the random selection is a key component. It is okay (and desired) for the algorithm to potentially visit the same element more than once, which means this will wind up being more than O(n).

Comment: use `random.shuffle` and iterate through elements once. Waiting for random to land on the last few indexes is the killer.

Comment: This algo is actually part of a bigger program modeling interactions between individuals. Because you can "meet" the same person more than once, I didn't think it was appropriate to use something like `random.shuffle`, but maybe I should incorporate it in some way to "cheat" a little when I have large N.

Comment: If you want to visit elements repeatedly then there is no order(n) solution. If you can pick how many extra visits you want—say, m total visits where m ≥ n—then there is a Θ(m) algorithm. Pick m-n (that is, m minus n) random elements, then pick all n elements in random order (say, by shuffling an array of indices).

Comment: Just to follow up on this. After doing some testing, the real issue was that I was using `list.remove(x)` later on in the code. Replacing `choice = random.choice(list)` with `index = list[random.randint(0,len(list)-1)]` allowed me to use `list.pop(index)` later on, which dramatically sped things up to the point where it's fast enough to deal with the large N that this program deals with.